# KeyError when attempting to plot METAR

Tags: python-xarray, metpy

When attempting to plot surface observations from the THREDDS data server, my script hangs or returns a `KeyError`. Below is the code:

```py
metarfile = TDSCatalog('http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/'
                       'nws/metar/ncdecoded/files/latest.xml')
latestmetar = metarfile.datasets[0]

file = latestmetar.remote_access(use_xarray=True)

parsed_temp = file.metpy.parse_cf('air_temperature')
parsed_td = file.metpy.parse_cf('dew_point_temperature')
parsed_mslp = file.metpy.parse_cf('air_pressure_at_sea_level')

parsed_temp = parsed_temp * 9/5 + 32
parsed_td = parsed_td * 9/5 + 32

prj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_latitude=35,
                            central_longitude=-98,
                            standard_parallels=(30, 60))

points = prj.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), file['longitude'].values,
                                                  file['latitude'].values)

file[mpcalc.reduce_point_density(points, 100000)]

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=prj)

ax.set_extent((-104.1, -95.5, 32.1, 39.1))

ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('50m'),linewidth=.5,
                                                 edgecolor='black',
                                                 zorder=5)

metarplots = StationPlot(ax, file['longitude'].values, file['latitude'].values,
                             clip_on=True, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                             fontsize=12)

metarplots.plot_parameter('NW', file['air_temperature'], color='red')
metarplots.plot_parameter('SW', file['dew_point_temperature'], color='green')
metarplots.plot_parameter('NE', file['air_pressure_at_sea_level'],
                                color='yellow')
```

When hashing out the MetPy `reduce_point_density` to perhaps resolve the problem of too many data points, the code hangs with no error message. Additionally, when printing the data from `parsed_td` it returns the values I want.

```
<xarray.DataArray 'dew_point_temperature' (recNum: 15331)>
array([69.8 , 41.  , 32.  , ..., 78.98, 60.8 , 62.96], dtype=float32)
Dimensions without coordinates: recNum
```

I'm really not sure where to start troubleshooting this problem as I haven't before plotted point data. Any help would be helpful!

EDIT: Include error message.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 945, in _copy_listed
    variables[name] = self._variables[name]
KeyError: True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mslp_vis.py", line 63, in <module>
    file[mpcalc.reduce_point_density(points, 100000)]
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1060, in __getitem__
    return self._copy_listed(np.asarray(key))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 948, in _copy_listed
    self._variables, name, self._level_coords, self.dims)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 68, in _get_virtual_variable
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: True
```

Comment: Please share the error message, and have a closer look to the parse_cf function because it might be that coordinates are missing for the dew_point data. It is also recommend to do no operations on a whole xarray Datarray. So call parsed_td.dew_point_temperature = parsed_td.dew_point_temperature * 9/5 + 32

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that! I edited the post to include the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is how the netCDF is written. It comes in the discrete sampling geometry (DSG) format, which is different than the typical gridded format. As a result, the mask computed here is only valid for the Lat and Long variables. For the data variables, a new mask has to be computed, based on the valid stations that remain after the initial mask is calculated. The following code adapts the original code to demonstrate this full process. Note that the loop is slow, and maybe could be refactored.

```
metarfile = TDSCatalog('http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/'
                       'nws/metar/ncdecoded/files/latest.xml')
latestmetar = metarfile.datasets[0]

file = latestmetar.remote_access(use_xarray=True)

parsed_temp = file.metpy.parse_cf('air_temperature')
parsed_td = file.metpy.parse_cf('dew_point_temperature')
parsed_mslp = file.metpy.parse_cf('air_pressure_at_sea_level')

parsed_temp = parsed_temp * 9/5 + 32
parsed_td = parsed_td * 9/5 + 32

prj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_latitude=35,
                            central_longitude=-98,
                            standard_parallels=(30, 60))

points = prj.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), file['longitude'].values,
                                                  file['latitude'].values)

points[2477, 0:2] = [0,0]
mask = mpcalc.reduce_point_density(points, 100000)

mask_stations = []
for x in file['parent_index'].values:
    if x in file['station'][mask]:
        mask_stations.append(True)
    else:
        mask_stations.append(False)

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=prj)

ax.set_extent((-104.1, -95.5, 32.1, 39.1))

ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('50m'),linewidth=.5,
                                                 edgecolor='black',
                                                 zorder=5)

metarplots = StationPlot(ax, file['longitude'].values[mask], file['latitude'].values[mask],
                             clip_on=True, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                             fontsize=12)

metarplots.plot_parameter('NW', file['air_temperature'][mask_stations].metpy.convert_units('degF'), color='red')
metarplots.plot_parameter('SW', file['dew_point_temperature'][mask_stations], color='green')
metarplots.plot_parameter('NE', file['air_pressure_at_sea_level'][mask_stations],
                                color='blue')
```

Comment: I spoke too soon, code worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am curious though, what does ```points[2477, 0:2] = [0,0]``` signify?

Comment: Those points had infinity values for me. I guess you should really change those to NaNs maybe? I just had to remove the infinity values in order for things to work.